# No network in my imported vm in ESXi 5 which is deployed in Workstation

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, esxi

I have imported my VM to ESXi and when run the VM, I realized that the VM has no network connection. It says that 2 connections are cable unplugged.

Then I see my VM settings, here what I got:
[image: vm settings]

See the permission of user in Permission tab of that VM that I used to login to my VSphere Client:
[image: user permission]

This is the host network properties:
[image: virtual switch]

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: is your vm powered on?

Comment: That screenshot taken when my vm is off. When it is on, the Connected checkbox is enabled but when tick it, it will give other error.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: I can't remember what is the error and I can't turn on my VM now because I need to re-import the VM again. Btw do you know how to solve this http://lonesysadmin.net/2010/11/02/remember-permissions-on-virtual-switches/ ? In my Inventory menu, there is no Networking menu.

Comment: Does the host have any network adapters? If so, are they recognized by ESXi?

Comment: Can you please guide me how to check that? I am still learning :D Is it under Configuration tab > Networking in host?

Comment: If I run `esxcfg-nics -l` in ESXi, it will list: `vmnic0  xxxx:xx:xx.xx e1000       Up   1000Mbps  Full   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx 1500   Intel Corporation 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper)`

Comment: It looks like the host does have network adapters that are recognized. Have you created a vSwitch?

Comment: Please see my updated post :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working. I need to edit .vmx of my VM and add following:

```
ethernet0.networkName="###"
ethernet1.networkName="###"
```

where ### is the VM network name specified under Virtual Machine Port Group. In below image, "VM Network" is the example

[image: Host VM Network]